# How to align code with left and right indentaion in VIM

Tags: vim, indentation

I have this code:

```
struct
  {
     uint32_t                rsvd0           :  8;
     uint32_t                tag             :  8;       
     uint32_t                status_qualifer : 16;
  } dw0;
```

I want to format it like following:

```
struct
  {
     uint32_t                rsvd0 :  8;
     uint32_t                  tag :  8;
     uint32_t      status_qualifer : 16;
  } dw0;
```

How do I do this in vim.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've came up with something like this:

```
/\v\s{10}(<\w+>)(\s{2,})?\ze :
:%s//\2\1
```

NOTE: I'm using very magic search `\v` to make the search easier

In the substitution part we are using regex groups (), so we are ignoring 10 spaces before the second word `\s{10}`. You can change how many spaces do you want to get rid of. 
Then we are creating a group that matches the second word `(<\w+>)`. Following that two spaces or more (optional) `\s{2,})?`. We then, finish the match by using the awesome vim `\ze`, a space and colon.

The command uses the last search `//` which is replaced by group 2 followed by group 1.

My final result was:

```
struct
  {
     uint32_t                rsvd0 :  8;
     uint32_t                  tag :  8;
     uint32_t      status_qualifer : 16;
  } dw0;
```

Another approach involves two global commands, where the first one
just removes a bunchh of spaces between the columns.

```
:g/_t/normal wel10x
:g/  :/normal wwelldt:bP
```

NOTE: you can select the lines above and run: `:@+`. I've tested those commands, and the same applies to the first solution.

the first global command executes a normal command at the lines that match `_t`
the command is:

```
we ....................... jump to the first word and to the end of it
l ........................ move one position to the right
10x ...................... erases 10 chars
```

The seccond global command runs over lines that match `:`
at least two spaces followed by coma.

```
ww ....................... jump to the second word
e ........................ jump to the end of the word
ll ....................... move the cursor twice to the right
dt: ...................... delete until before :
bP ....................... move to the word before and pastes the default register
```

For more information:

```
:h \ze
:h magic
:h regex
:h normal
:h global
```

Answer (score 1):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](https://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)

Your question is a great candidate to evaluate each plugin. Check out their documentation pages, try out the one that looks the most promising and understandable to you. (Ideally report back here, with a comment, which one you chose.)

Answer (score 0):

Another regex to align the second code column is:

```
:%s/\(\s\+\)\(\w\+\)\(\s\+\):/\1\3\2 :/g
```

This just move spaces from ahead to behind the second column.